# Cannot log in to Network account on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, samba

I am imaging a lot of Surface Pro 2 Tablets, with our organization's Windows 8.1 Pro image. It is working for all but one, which is giving me a login issue.

It's joined to our Samba 3 domain, and has local Administrator access for the techs to use, and relies on network log in for everyone else. When logged in as the Local Admin account, I can access shares just fine, after running a `net use \\server\share /user:luke *` command. However, if I log off (or restart), and try logging in with my server credentials, it gives me a yellow message, saying **An attempt was made to logon but the network logon service was not started**. Very cryptic anyways...

So, I checked Google, and it told me to make sure that the `netlogon` service was started. It was set to Manual, so I changed it to Automatic, and started it manually. Still can't log in to Windows directly.

I had to check the services, and was told to try checking the **Remote Procedural call* service, but that was set to Automatic as well. After waiting for approx. 30 minutes, with the tablet powered on, it connected just fine. I then rebooted the tablet to try to log in with a new user account - But no go, with the same error message.

The Network status icon in the lower left corner of the logon screen shows that it's connected to my network, with full strength. When I log in, it does show the network as a Private Network with Sharing enabled.

What else can I do to get this to log in the first time, every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, resetting the TCP/IP Stack fixed the issue. To do this:

1. Log in as an Administrative user
2. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to bring up the Admin Menu, then select **Command Prompt (Admin)**. Choose to continue if prompted by UAC.
3. Type `netsh winsock reset`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type `shutdown -r -t 0` to reset the system, and log in immediately.